# Scala: "map" vs "foreach" - is there any reason to use "foreach" in practice?

Tags: scala, foreach, scala-collections, side-effects

In Scala collections, if one wants to iterate over a collection (without returning results, i.e. doing a side effect on every element of collection), it can be done either with

```
final def foreach(f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

or

```
final def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): SomeCollectionClass[B]
```

With the exception of possible lazy mapping(*), from an end-user perspective, I see zero differences in these invocations:

```
myCollection.foreach { element =>
  doStuffWithElement(element);
}

myCollection.map { element =>
  doStuffWithElement(element);
}
```

given that I can just ignore what map outputs. I can't think of any specific reason why two different methods should exist & be used, when `map` seems to include all the functionality of `foreach`, and, in fact, I would be pretty much impressed if an intelligent compiler & VM won't optimize out that collection object creation given that it's not assigned to anything, or read, or used anywhere.

So, the question is - am I right - and there are no reasons to call `foreach` anywhere in one's code?

**Notes:**

(*) The lazy mapping concept, [as throughly illustrated in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631778/scala-map-on-iterator-does-not-produce-side-effects), might change things a bit and justify usage of `foreach`, but as far as I can see, one specifically needs to stumble upon a `LazyMap`, normal

(**) If one's not *using* a collection, but *writing* one, then one would quickly stumble upon the fact that `for` comprehension syntax syntax is in fact a syntax sugar that generates "foreach" call, i.e. these two lines generate fully equivalent code:

```
for (element <- myCollection) { doStuffWithElement(element); }
myCollection.foreach { element => doStuffWithElement(element); }
```

So if one cares about other people using that collection class with `for` syntax, one might still want to implement `foreach` method.

Comment: It's nice to use `foreach` instead of `map` to differentiate between side-effecting and non-side-effecting functions. I don't care if the compiler optimizes one for the other. The difference makes the purpose of the code more apparent.

Comment: To go one step further then LimbSoup, I prefer to use `for ..` (sans yield) instead of `.foreach` directly as it further (to me) shows the divide between iteration *for* side-effects and a transformation for the sequence. Also, it can be dangerous to assume the sequence being iterated is not-lazy.

Comment: In contrast to you, *I* would be strongly impressed if the current Scala compiler and/or the JVM are able to optimize the `map` to the `foreach` code if the result is not used. This appears to me as an **extremely** non-trivial optimization.

Answer (score 17):

I can think of a couple motivations:

1. When the `foreach` is the last line of a method that is of type `Unit` your compiler will not give an warning but will with `map` (and you need `-Ywarn-value-discard` on).  Sometimes you get `warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses` using `map` but wouldn't with `foreach`.
2. General readability - a reader can know that your mutating some state without returning something at a glance, but greater cognitive resources would be required to understand the same operation if `map` was used
3. Further to 1. you also can have type checking when passing named functions around, then into `map` and `foreach`
4. Using `foreach` won't build a new list, so will be more efficient (thanks @Vishnu)

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but `Map` returns an immutable object, while `foreach` has a return type of `Unit`. So `foreach` is more memory efficient if your intent is just to read the content. Right?

Comment: Yup, Thanks @Vishnu

Comment: well, actually I think map returns the same type of collection as it was applied to. So if you apply it to a mutable collection, you should get back a new mutable collection.

Answer (score 8):

```
scala> (1 to 5).iterator map println
res0: Iterator[Unit] = non-empty iterator

scala> (1 to 5).iterator foreach println
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned in (*) - it's lazy mapping, which is the default on all iterators.

Comment: So your assertion in this question is that `foreach` and `map` are the same except when they're not?

Comment: My assertion is that "they are the same except for clearly outlined cases (*) and (**)", both of which, in my opinion, are fairly rare in average end-user practice.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be impressed if the builder machinery could be optimized away.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

implicit val cbf = new collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[Int],Int,List[Int]] {
def apply() = new collection.mutable.Builder[Int, List[Int]] {
val b = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]
override def +=(i: Int) = { println(s"Adding $i") ; b +=(i) ; this }
override def clear() = () ; override def result() = b.result() }
def apply(from: List[Int]) = apply() }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[Int],Int,List[Int]] = $anon$2@e3cee7b

scala> List(1,2,3) map (_ + 1)
Adding 2
Adding 3
Adding 4
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

scala> List(1,2,3) foreach (_ + 1)
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `CanBuildFrom`-related implicit stuff would generate here a hierarchy of classes on JVM level, including the one that would include `+=` method that actually does something besides constructing a variable that would be ultimately thrown away (and thus all that code could be safely skipped). Of course, a method that *does* something, especially when that something is a clear `invokevirtual` call, won't be optimized away.